# Converting number primitives (i32, f64, etc) to byte representations

Tags: types, rust

I am writing a library that encodes/decodes data to/from a binary format. Part of the format is numbers, which I'm using Rust's native primitive types for (like `i8`, `i64`, `f32` etc.).

Is there an easy, built-in way to convert these data types into/from binary, i.e. convert a `f64`/`f32`/`i64`/etc. into a `Vec<u8>`? Likewise is there a way to convert 4 `u8`s (in a `Vec<u8>` say) into an `f32`?

Comment: Please, can you mark the Nicholas Rishel's answer as accepted? That's the canonical answer now, and the oldest ones with `transmute` examples can be misleading.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no safe built-in support for reading/writing primitives from/to a byte array in Rust at the moment. There are several community libraries for that, however, [byteorder](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) being the most used one:

```
extern crate byteorder;

use byteorder::{LittleEndian, WriteBytesExt};
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let i: i64 = 12345;
    let mut bs = [0u8; mem::size_of::<i64>()];
    bs.as_mut()
        .write_i64::<LittleEndian>(i)
        .expect("Unable to write");

    for i in &bs {
        println!("{:X}", i);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can always cast raw pointers. For example, you can turn `*const i64` into `*const i8` and then convert it into an appropriate byte slice `&[u8]`. However, this is easy to get wrong, `unsafe` and platform-dependent due to endiannness, so it should be used only as a last resort:

```
use std::{mem, slice};

fn main() {
    let i: i64 = 12345;
    let ip: *const i64 = &i;
    let bp: *const u8 = ip as *const _;
    let bs: &[u8] = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(bp, mem::size_of::<i64>()) };

    for i in bs {
        println!("{:X}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `std::slice::from_raw_parts` is less code and also marked stable. Still unsafe for the same reasons, though!

Comment: `byteorder` solves it exactly. When I said "built in" I should have specified that something from crates.io would suffice.

Answer (score 114):

As of Rust 1.32 you can use `{to,from}_{ne,le,be}_bytes` for integral types.

```
let begin = 1234_i32;
let bytes = begin.to_ne_bytes();
let and_back = i32::from_ne_bytes(bytes);
```

For floating point you still have to rely on prior methods.

Comment: What prior methods?

Comment: @pfincent Please see [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754905/298941)

Answer (score 56):

Rust 1.40 has: [`{to,from}_{ne,le,be}_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=to_ne_bytes).

Converting a number to bytes and back (works for floats and integers after rust 1.40):

```rust
let x = 65535_i32;
let x_bytes = x.to_be_bytes();                  // x_bytes = [0, 0, 255, 255]
let original_x = i32::from_be_bytes(x_bytes);   // original_x = 65535 = x
```

## Converting float before Rust 1.40

Rust 1.32 has: [`{to,from}_{ne,le,be}_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=to_ne_bytes) (only for integers), [`to_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=f%3A%3Ato_bits), and [`from_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=f%3A%3Afrom_bits).

Converting a float to bytes and back:

```rust
let y = 255.255_f32;
let y_bytes = y.to_bits().to_be_bytes();
let original_y = f32::from_bits(u32::from_be_bytes(y_bytes)); // original_y = 255.255 = y
```

According to the Rust documentation `from_bits` can have [portability issues](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.from_bits).

Answer (score 16):

`std::mem::transmute` can be used, although it is `unsafe`:

```
fn main() {
    let var1 = 12345678_i64;
    let raw_bytes: [i8; 8] = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(var1) };
    for byte in &raw_bytes {
        println!("{}", byte);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Please be sure the size of the two variables are exactly equal.

Comment: Ensuring the correct size can be done by using `std::mem::size_of::<i64>()` instead of `8` in the array

Comment: Few things: raw_bytes should be `[u8; 8]` (or `mem::size_of` as suggested) and if the sizes do not match, `transmute` won't work: *"cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types"* so it is "kind of safe".

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to print the bytes or have them in a `str` representation, simply use the `:b` notation in a format brace

```
fn main() {
    println!("This is the binary of int {:b}", 4 as i32);
}
```

This prints

`This is the binary of int 100`