# Reinterpreting u32 as array of four u8

Tags: casting, rust

Assume I have an array of four `u8`, let's say - as a field of a struct:

```rust
#[repr(C, packed)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeStruct<'a> {
    header: [u8; 4],
    // ... other fields ...
}
```

I would like to efficiently read it as `u32` and then reinterpret into such an array - instead of calling four successive `read_u8`. Currently, I'm using [byteorder](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) crate and `transmute`:

```rust
unsafe {
   let input = metadata_bytes.read_u32::<LittleEndian>().unwrap();
   data.header = std::mem::transmute::<u32, [u8; 4]>(input);
}
```

It works but I'm completely not sure whether it is not miserably convoluted approach. So the questions are:

1. is my approach ok? Can it be done better/faster/more idiomatic?
2. in the current approach, does `transmute` copy those 4 bytes or just reinterprets it?

PS. I can't use `slice::from_raw_parts_mut` for the whole struct as it contains dynamically sized fields inside.

Comment: And the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307474/how-can-i-convert-a-buffer-of-a-slice-of-bytes-u8-to-an-integer

Comment: Note to the newcomers: you should use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581990/4498831)

Comment: Great, thanks @hellow! Somehow I've overlooked `to_le_bytes`...